# Zlib compresion technique in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, compression, zlib

I am new to .net. I created one website.I want to implement Zlib compression technique for compressing data in each every page, so that i can access open my website quickly.But i don't know where I have to write code for that and how to implement it. Can yo send me the sample application code or zip file.

Comment: Generally the web server can sort this out for you. What are you using - IIS? Which version of IIS / which version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about compressing web pages delivered from the server then gzip is used.

[IIS6 Example](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true)